# Shrink height to content size

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this UL with content that changes on the fly.  I figured out a fairly neat solution to smoothly increasing the height as new items get added, but I'm stuck on the reverse.

Through CSS, initial `height` is set to 0, with `overflow: hidden`. A mutation observer watches the element, and as content changes it modifies the `.style.height` to equal the `.scrollHeight`, which combined with a transition in the CSS makes a nice smooth expansion to the element. Unfortunately it doesn't work in reverse, because of course `.scrollHeight` refers to the fully sized element. Is there some way to get the calculated height of `fit-content` without actually changing `.style.height`?

Vanilla solutions only please (no jquery, etc). This is for an offline project I'm trying to keep to one file.

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
 observer.target.style.height = observer.target.scrollHeight + 'px'
})
observer.target = document.querySelector('#animated')
observer.observe(observer.target, { childList: true })

var lines = 0

function demo(inc) {
 lines += inc
 observer.target.innerHTML = '<li>Demonstration</li>'.repeat(lines)
}
```

```css
#animated {
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid black;
 transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="demo(1)">Demo Expand</button>
<button onclick="demo(-1)">Demo Contract</button>

<ul id="animated"></ul>
```

Comment: Your observer is not working correctly.

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: because you are not subtracting the child height from parent height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the total height of `children`

```
[...observer.target.children].reduce((a, i) => a + i.scrollHeight, 0) + 'px'
```

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  observer.target.style.height = [...observer.target.children].reduce((a, i) => a + i.scrollHeight, 0) + 'px'
})
observer.target = document.querySelector('#animated')
observer.observe(observer.target, {
  childList: true
})

var lines = 0

function demo(inc) {
  lines += inc
  observer.target.innerHTML = '<li>Demonstration</li>'.repeat(lines)
}
```

```css
#animated {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="demo(1)">Demo Expand</button>
<button onclick="demo(-1)">Demo Contract</button>

<ul id="animated"></ul>
```

Comment: I would like to add this ontop of your solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc. You could dynamically rescale your `#animated` height using this css function. If you use a css preprocessor like `sass` or `less` you could also include your predefined (or dynamically generated) children inside the calc for a truly responsive design. @therks

Comment: That's good to know for future use, but not helpful here. A preprocessor requires a server of some kind, right? As I mentioned in the post, this is used in an offline project. It's essentially an .html file just running on a laptop at work to help fill out some paperwork.